# Rails Simple_Form Saving Values as NULL in Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

So I'm new to Rails and I've been playing around with it by trying to create a very simple to do list based on current user. So far I have authentication handled with Devise and forms are rendered with simple_form gem. Everything works fine up until I try to add a new task to the database. For some reason when I submit the form, it inputs NULL into the db columns (except of course the id column which increments)...it's like the values are getting lost in transmission or something weird. Anyway, here's what I have:

Controller:

```
class TodoController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @todo_list = Todo.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).all
    @task = Todo.new
  end

  def create
    @todo_list = Todo.all
    @task = Todo.new(params[:task])
    if @task.save
      flash[:notice] = "Task Added"
      redirect_to todos_path
    else
      render :action => 'index'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @todo_list = Todo.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Task Deleted"
    redirect_to todos_path
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  attr_accessible :user_id, :task_name, :task_description
end
```

View:

```
<h2>To Do List</h2>
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>

<div class="span11">
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Task</th>
          <th>Description</th>           
      </tr>
  </thead>   
  <tbody>
  <% @todo_list.each do |todo| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= todo.task_name %></td>
        <td><%= todo.task_description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to("Delete", todos_path, :confirm => 'Delete task?', :method => :delete, :class => 'btn btn-mini') %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
</div>
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for @task, :url => todos_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :task_name, :as => :string %>
    <%= f.input :task_description, :as => :string  %> 
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %
```

It's probably something really simple, I just can't seem to spot it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the output from your rails logs? At a minimum, I think you will have to put something like  `@todo.user = current_user` before your save in the `create`.

Comment: you don't need to specify :url and :method, just put `<%= simple_form_for @task do |f| %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the create method in your controller, shouldn't the params be

```
params[:todo]
```

rather than

```
params[:task]
```

the name of that param is dictated by the model name of your instance, not what you name the variable.

Nothing lethal but naming your instance variables that have a model tied to it differently is not the best practice to do, can lead to a lot of confusion later on.